# Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook ideal window size

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf, sxssf

I am trying to produce a large excel (~10 MB) with multiple sheets (5). The current implementation was using `XSSFWorkbook` but now we are running into `OutOfMemoryError` in the deployed environment so made the switch to use `SXSSFWorkbook`. The constructor takes in a window size as an argument. I tried with the default size but ran into this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to write a row[4] in the range [0,8] that is already written to disk.
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.createRow(SXSSFSheet.java:125)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.createRow(SXSSFSheet.java:61)
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil.getRow(CellUtil.java:126)
at org.apache.poi.ss.util.RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(RegionUtil.java:75)
```

Updating the window size to 500 seems to have 'fixed' the issue but I am still wondering if that is the ideal solution for this problem or should I be doing something else?

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(null, 500);
```

I saw the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868325/apache-poi-getrow-returns-null-and-createrow-fails) but still wasn't clear. I am using JDK 11, poi-ooxml 5.2.2 and am running on a Mac.

Comment: Bigger window size means more memory is required, but allows you to change your mind over a wider range of rows

Comment: @Gagravarr but what would be the ideal value for it? I'm wondering if allowing the developer to configure it is a good enough solution or if there are better ways to solve it. I don't have visibility from a future data standpoint

Comment: There is no ideal for everyone, it depends on how much memory you want to use, and how far back you need to modify rows